# SendMessage WM_SETTEXT throws SecurityPermission Error

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I am having trouble with on of our clients machines throwing an error when the SendMessage(WM_SETTEXT..) API is called. It works fine on other customer's machines and all our machines here. The error thrown is a System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission. I Googled but could not find any references as to a reason. Even when the hwnd does not point to a real window there is no error in my testing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, string lParam);
...

private void RegisterWithCaller()
{
    if (this.hwndCaller != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        if (FormMode.DELIVERY == this.formMode)
        {
            SendMessage(this.hwndCaller, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "hWndInvoiceDisplay=" + this.txtCommunicate.Handle.ToInt32().ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            SendMessage(this.hwndCaller, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "hWndBOLsDisplay=" + this.txtCommunicate.Handle.ToInt32().ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, forgot: private const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean, [SecurityPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securitypermission) isn't really an error that can be thrown, it's a set of permissions...?

Comment: I'm afraid that is all the error really displays other than the stack trace information.

Comment: Are you running your application "as administrator"?

Comment: IIRC, using the interop stuff (DllImport) requires that the exe runs with Full Trust - and if the exe isn't running *local* on the machine, you can get an error. So if you run a managed exe off a network share, you'll get an error; copy it to a local drive, and it can work. There might be a similar issue here. How is the client deploying/running this code on the machine where it's not working vs the ones where it does work?

Comment: Also; the issue you are having is perhaps related to using DllImport at all; not the specific API (SendMessage) or message. You can check this by trying to use some other DllImport'ed API, eg. MessageBox or OutputDebugString. (Also; wParam should be IntPtr not int, though that's unrelated to this issue.)